# a string or function that includes multiple variables (c++)

Tags: c++, string, function, variables, include

I've searched multiple places for this and watched through the entire "TheNewBoston" C++ guide on youtube, and am yet to find an answer for this.

I'm writing a program to practice my c++ skills, I'm still a noob but I think this is possible I just don't know how to do it.

The program i'm trying to make is one that records how many reps you do for a certain excercise when training in the gym.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string biceps = "biceps";
    string triceps = "triceps";
    string quads = "quads";
    string muscleChoice;

    cout << "Welcome to MyPT!" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout <<  "What are you going to be training today?" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "**Biceps** \n\n**Triceps** \n\n**Quads**" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cin >> muscleChoice;
    if ((muscleChoice == "biceps") || (muscleChoice == "triceps") || (muscleChoice == "quads"))
    {
        cout << "working" << endl;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

That's essentially what I want, and that works. But obviously if I was to have more possibilities, then that could get messy. What I want is something that looks like this.
(Obviously the function wouldn't be this long, just tried to explain it better)

```
cin >> muscleChoice;

if (muscleChoice == oneFunctionThatIncludesAllThoseStrings)
{
    cout << "working"
}
```

does anybody know how to do that?

(Please explain your answer as I might not understand, I'm noob)

Comment: You mean a `std::set<std::string>` and a `.find()` invoke ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) of exercise strings, and then check that the input string is a member of that set:

```
std::set<std::string> exercises{"biceps", "triceps", "quads"};
```

then

```
if (exercises.find(muscleChoice) != exercises.end())
{
  std::cout << "working";
}
```

If you want to keep a tally of reps, you could use an [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)  instead:

```
std::map<std::string, unsigned int> exercises;

if (exercises.find(muscleChoice) != exercises.end())
{
  std::cout << "working";
  exercises[muscleChoice]++; // increase count for this muscle choice
}
```

Comment: Do I need to #include anything? it says 'set' is not a member of 'std'

Comment: @user2716905 Yes, `<set>` for `std::set` and `<map>` for `std::map`. I added links to references which tell you which headers you need.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you may want do to is having all the strings you want to test for equality in an array and a function that loops through the array and checks for any equality.

```
string commands[] = { "bicep", "tricep", "quad" };
```

Then to check the equality:

```
bool testForEquality( string s ){
   for( int i=0; i<3; i++ ){
      if( s == commands[i] ) return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

As for the usage:

```
cin >> muscleChoice;

if ( testForEquality(muscleChoice) )
{
    cout << "working"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

#include <algorithm> // find function
#include <vector> // dynamic array to store choices

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> accepted_choices;
    accepted_choices.push_back("biceps"); // add a choice
    accepted_choices.push_back("tricep");
    accepted_choices.push_back("quad");

    cout << "Welcome to MyPT!" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout <<  "What are you going to be training today?" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "**Biceps** \n\n**Triceps** \n\n**Quads**" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cin >> muscleChoice;
    if (find(accepted_choices.begin(), accepted_choices.end(), muscleChoice) != accepted_choices.end()) // find returns container.end() if it failed to find
    {
        cout << "working" << endl;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do there is simply use a list of choices and pick one of them by using if statement.
An option would be to assign the different choices to an array of strings like this;

```
string Body_Parts[3] = { "biceps", "triceps", "quads" };
```

and use this to your advantage;

```
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {    
        if(muscleChoice==Body_Parts[i])
            cout<<"working"<<endl; 
    }
```

The piece of code above would compare the muscleChoice of yours int to the array of all choices and print out whatever you want when it finds a match.

Answer (score 0):

C++98 solution:

```
string muscles[3] = { "biceps", "triceps", "quads" } ;
vector<string> vec(muscles, muscles+3);
set<string> muscles_set(vec.begin(), vec.end());

if ( muscles_set.count(muscleChoice) )
```